# Perl how to set wildcards in a variable to be used to find files (if only partial file name is known)

Tags: perl, variables, wildcard

Here is the code in which i read a file which arrives in ARGV[0] and read a line at a time and use the line as partial name of a file, whose location is unknown hence a find is used to find the location of a file if exist, then apply the second parameter ARGV[1] to grep on that file.

```
if ($#ARGV != 1)
{
    print "Usage : splfind.pl fullpath_of_input_file_contains_partial_filesnames_to_search pattern_to_search_on_filename_matched_file";
    exit 1;
}

my $partfilelist_file=$ARGV[0];
my $stringtosearch=$ARGV[1];

my @partfilelist = split /\n/, `cat $partfilelist_file`;
while (defined ($partfileentry = pop(@partfilelist)))
{
    print "===============================================================================\n";    
    #print "Searching for file with partial name $partfileentry as [find . -type f -name '*$partfileentry*.c']\n";
    my $foundfile = `find . -type f -name '*$partfileentry*.c'`;
    if ($foundfile)
    {
        print "Found file $foundfile\n";
        system ("grep $stringtosearch $foundfile");
    }
    else
    {
        print "No file is found...\n";
    }
}
```

Output i get now

```
[rajeguna@ukstbuild3 suites]$ splfind.pl ~/ipclient-test.txt SEARCH_
===============================================================================
*.c']find . -type f -name '*DMS_1319_4MS_1319_4
No file is found...
===============================================================================
*.c']find . -type f -name '*DMS_1319_3MS_1319_3
No file is found...
===============================================================================
*.c']find . -type f -name '*DMS_1288_1MS_1288_1
No file is found...
===============================================================================
*.c']find . -type f -name '*DMS_1283_1MS_1283_1
No file is found...
===============================================================================
*.c']find . -type f -name '*DMS_1282_2MS_1282_2
No file is found...
===============================================================================
*.c']find . -type f -name '*DMS_1282_1MS_1282_1
No file is found...
===============================================================================
```

My input file contains this

```
DMS_0307_6
DMS_0307_7
DMS_0392_1
DMS_0393_1
DMS_0397_10
DMS_0397_6
DMS_0397_7
DMS_0397_8
DMS_0397_9
DMS_0549_20
DMS_0549_22
```

Comment: This question can be phrased more clearly.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you want to use the glob operator `<>`.  Just try to specify the wilcard directly in the `find` command:

```
my @files = `find . -type f -name *DMS_0307_*.c`;
```

UPDATE: With a variable (you may need to use single quotes for your shell):

```
my $partfileentry = 'DMS_1189_';
my @files = `find . -type f -name '*$partfileentry*.c'`;
```

Comment: but this (DMS_0307_) will come on a variable, when i use it with the variable it does not work                      my $foundfile = `find . -type f -name *$partfileentry*.c`;

Comment: thanks @toolic, but it still does not work for me. See my update block, where i have added the actual code.

Answer (score 0):

Use `File::Find`, which will let you avoid race-conditions in the filesystem, etc.  Match the filename in your `sub wanted`.

```
sub wanted {
  return unless /\.c\z/ and index($_, $partfileentry) >= 0;
  # some manipulation here, with $_ as the filename,
  # while chdir'd to the correct directory
}
```